# Adding Custom c++ function in chromium and call them in browser

Tags: c++, chromium, v8

I am trying to write custom function in bootstrapper.cc under v8/src/init.

```
 int helloworld(){
  return 0;
}
```

When it try to call it from chromium console, it throws undefined.
[image]

Comment: You should look at the documentation of v8 on how to export functions. That's not how you do it

Comment: Thanks. Can you provide some reference link or guide ? I tried but couldn't find what i need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look around `bootstrapper.cc` to see how other built-in functions are installed. Examples you could look at include `Array` and `DataView` (or any other, really).

There is no way to simply define a C++ function of a given name and have that show up in JavaScript. Instead, you have to define a property on the global object; and the function itself needs to have the right calling convention, and process its parameters / prepare its return value appropriately so that it can be called from JavaScript. You can't just take or return an `int`.

If you find it inconvenient to work with C++, an alternative might be to develop a Chrome extension, which would allow you to use JavaScript for the implementation, and also remove the need to compile/maintain/update your own build (which is a *lot* of work!). There is no existing guide for how to extend V8 in the way you're asking, because that approach is so much work that we don't recommend doing it like this (though of course it is possible -- you just have to read enough of the existing C++ source to understand how it's done).

Comment: Thank You. 
How can we define a property on global object?
You may have created some function in past. Is it possible for you to share a real example please ?

Comment: The real examples are in bootstrapper.cc. You'll have to read some of the surrounding code to understand what the various helper functions do. The key bit is the call to `JSObject::AddProperty`.